# finding limit of a given function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0} {\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^4}\right)}{x}}$$

This question is an excerpt from a question in complex analysis that dealt with determining the analyticity of the given function. I am stuck here. please help me out

Comment: Real or complex? For complex $x\to 0$, the limit doesn't exist. For real $x\to 0$, it does.

Comment: If you are working with real $x$, try $y = \frac{1}{x}$ and let $y\rightarrow\infty$ (for $x\rightarrow 0^+$ in the original problem), and $y\rightarrow-\infty$ (for $x\rightarrow 0^{-}$). You should get $0$ as the limit in both cases.

Comment: @LordSoth: that's much better than the idea I was trying to put together of using L'Hôpital's rule in reverse...

Comment: @abiessu Thanks :) I don't know about "L'Hopital in reverse," but L'Hopital itself may get a little messy in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x^{-1}$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{e^{x^{-4}}}{x}=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac{y}{e^{y^4}}=0$ by L'Hopita. Similarly, we have that $\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{e^{x^{-4}}}{x}=0$.